# finding more information on journald failure

Tags: systemd-journald

System locked up with console full of

```
systemd-journald[123]: Failed to write entry to /var/log/journal/b5...1c/user-100.journal (29 items, 820 bytes) despite vacuuming, ignoring: input/output error (Dropped 798 similar messages)"
```

After a reset I could not find any logs that hinted at IO error. But I am guessing IO errors would not be stored in IO :(

Now, why was the terminal full of those ignored garbage when the first IO error that effectively killed journald would be the utmost importance?

Anyway to have journald not litter the console when something fatal like that happens? Or anyplace where the system log would have any hint about the cause?

Comment: Send logs to a remote host if you don't want them to be lost. Also, check settings `ForwardToConsole` and similar in `journald.conf`.

Comment: forwarding logs to remote host is a really overkill suggestion for a end user home laptop.